# Generate all coordinates of earth?

Tags: loops, get, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Does somebody know an algorithm that calculates/generates all coordinates of earth?
I want to generate a dot mesh with a very high resolution. Each dot represents one real coordinate of earth. (latitude and longitude with minutes and seconds or in decimal format)
I am not so into coordinates, is it somehow possible to get them all?

Answer (score 2):

the x or longitude range on earth is from -180.0 to 180.0
The y or latitudinal range on earth is -90.0 to 90.0
The unit is degrees, the distance between two degrees (on equator) is about 111 km.

Choose your step, then loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but "all the coordinates" is very vague. There are an infinite amount of coordinates in the latitude longitude system. See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system).

Comment: Yes i was afraid so! ... Thanks for the answer! I will try smth else!